# vuejs count number of v-show elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to count a number of v-show elements (cards) that are showing below:

```
<v-layout v-show="checkArray(offer, speciality)">
   <v-flex>
      <v-card>
      ....
      <v-card>
   <v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

this seems easy in js but how to do it in vuejs?
My dom is changing dynamically due to search function, so I need to count children elements dynamically.

I've managed to use ref="", but as it is said in documentation:

"$refs are only populated after the component has been rendered, and it is not reactive. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid using $refs in templates or computed properties."

Answer (score 2):

You can get the children of a component via:

- `this.$children`
- Or, query the child elements via `this.$el.querySelector(...)`

  - If you want the underlying vue component add the elements have a `__vue__` propertiey
- Or, through the ref attribute and access it via `this.$refs['yourRefname']` but be aware only refs in `v-for` are turned into arrays.

Once you've got your elements you can count them like in regular JS, if you use `this.$ref` just read out the array length.

Comment: this seems correct, but I don't understand it with my level of experience

Comment: @gileneusz i made you a jsfiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/Hammster/r9jLyhw0/1/

Comment: I see your point, and this seems easy, but not working as expected on my code

Comment: got 
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'childElementCount' of undefined",
while I attached ref="mylist"
to 
<v-layout v-show="checkArray(offer, speciality)" ref="mylist">